# Evenly spaced elements while printing

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup

I have this piece of code:

```
for t in tables:
    print ""
    my_table = t
    rows = my_table.findAll('tr')
    for tr in rows:
      cols = tr.findAll('td')
      i = 0
      for td in cols:
          text = str(td.text).strip()
          print "{}{}".format(text if text !="" else "IP","|"),
          i=i+1
          if i == 2:
            print ""
            i = 0
            pass
```

"tables" is is a list of tables in HTML format. I am using beautifulsoup to parse in them.

Currently, the output that I get is:

```
Interface in| port-channel8.53| 
IP| 172.18.153.126/255.255.255.252| 
Router| bob| 
Route| route: 192.168.178.0/255.255.128.0 gw 172.18.145.106| 
Interface out| Ethernet2/5.103| 
IP| 172.18.145.105/255.255.255.252|
```

What I want to get is:

```
Interface in | port-channel8.53                                    | 
IP           | 172.18.153.126/255.255.255.252                      |  
Router       | bob                                                 |  
Route        | route: 192.168.178.0/255.255.128.0 gw 172.18.145.106| 
Interface out| Ethernet2/5.103                                     | 
IP           | 172.18.145.105/255.255.255.252                      |
"Placeholder"| another ip in the same td as the one up             |
"Placeholder"| another ip in the same td as the one up             |
```

How can I get this output?

**EDIT:**

Here is how 1 table is made:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Interface in</td>
    <td>Vlan800 (bob)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>172.26.128.3/255.255.255.224<br></br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Router</td>
    <td>bob2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Route</td>
    <td>route: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 gw 172.26.144.241</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Interface out</td>
    <td>Vlan1145 (bob3)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>172.26.144.245/255.255.255.240<br></br></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

(Yes, the empty  are on the real page)

**EDIT2:**
Problematic code:

```
<td>
195.233.112.4/255.255.255.0<br>
195.233.112.15/255.255.255.0<br>
195.233.112.3/255.255.255.0<br>
<br><br><br></td>
```

**EDIT 3:**

Sample code 2 (tha creates problems with solutions proposed)

```
<table class="nitrestable">
<tr>
    <td>Interface in</td>
    <td>GigabitEthernet1/1.103 (*global)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>172.18.145.106/255.255.255.252<br></br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Router</td>
    <td>*grt</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Route</td>
    <td>route: 172.18.145.106/255.255.255.128 gw 172.18.145.106</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Interface out</td>
    <td>Vlan71 (*global)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>172.18.145.106/255.255.255.0<br>
        172.18.146.106/255.255.255.0<br>
        172.18.147.106/255.255.255.0<br></br></br></br></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Some sample input data would be good.

Comment: Find some python `string.format` tutorial and focus on all the options, this will make your solution working soon.

Comment: Just think about the problem, the vertical lines aren't aligned. Why not? How can one iteration of the loop know the length of the next, in order to align correctly ? You need to figure out the maximum field lengths first, then print out the data.

Comment: Added sample of input data.

Answer (score 1):

You can supply a [format specifier](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec), e.g.

```
print "{0:14}|".format(text or "IP"),
```

or pad the string you're passing to `format` with [`str.ljust`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust):

```
print "{}|".format(str.ljust(text or "IP", 14)),
```

However, (as dilbert has just pointed out in the comments), you will need to do something to work out the size you require for each column.

Note that, as the empty string `""` evaluates `False` in a boolean context, you can simplify your `if` condition, and as the pipe `'|'` never changes you can put it in the template directly.

Answer (score 0):

It helps parsing the rows/cols into a list and then evaluating them. That makes it simple to compute the maximum widths of the columns (w1, w2 in the code). 
As the others said, once that width has been determined str.format() is what you want.

```
for t in tables:
    col = [[],[]]
    my_table = t
    rows = my_table.findAll('tr')
    for tr in rows:
      cols = tr.findAll('td')
      i = 0
      for td in cols:
          text = str(td.text).strip()
          col[i].append(text if text else "IP")
          i=i+1
          if i == 2:
            if '<br>' in text:
                text = text.replace('</br>','') #ignore </br>
                for t in text.split('<br>')[1:]: #first element has already been processed
                    if t: #only append if there is content
                        col[0].append(col[0][-1])  #duplicate the last entry of col[0]
                        col[1].append(t)
             i = 0
    w1 = max([len(x) for x in col[0]])
    w2 = max([len(x) for x in col[1]])
    for i in range(len(col[1]))
        s='{: <{}}|{: <{}}|'.format(col[0][i],w1,col[1][i],w2)
        print(s)
```

To explain the str.format(): `'{: <{}}'.format(x,y)` creates a whitespace-padded left adjusted string with the width `y` from the text `x`.

edit: added the additional parsing of multiple IPs/any fields were the second colum is separated with `<br>`

Comment: Hi. Your code is great! Only problem is when I have multiple items in the right column (separated by <br>.. so space basically). See the question with a sample of the code that created problems.

Comment: Fixed that. Works with multiple entries in one field of the second column by replicating the first column accordingly.

Comment: Are you sure? For me it still doesn't work when on the second column I have 3 entries and in the first only 1 :(

Comment: yeah that code had some minor bugs. Now it should work with your example.

Comment: I debugged your code. It never goes in  "if '<br>' in text" because text is just that, text, not html... so it can't find br tag in text.

Comment: Well at that point it would become useful to see your complete code. I don't know what kind of html parser you use or how it works, so I don't have any idea what the text variable actually is at that point (or more precisely: how the parser translates the <br> tag and how i should detect it then). So either add the complete code or print the text variable. If it is replaced with a newline just replace '<br>' with '\n' in my code and it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a 'simpler' script. Look up the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) keyword in Python.

```
import BeautifulSoup

raw_str = \
'''
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Interface in</td>
    <td>Vlan800 (bob)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>172.26.128.3/255.255.255.224<br></br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Router</td>
    <td>bob2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Route</td>
    <td>route: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 gw 172.26.144.241</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Interface out</td>
    <td>Vlan1145 (bob3)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>172.26.144.245/255.255.255.240<br></br></td>
</tr>
</table>
'''

org_str = \
'''
Interface in| port-channel8.53| 
IP| 172.18.153.126/255.255.255.252| 
Router| bob| 
Route| route: 192.168.178.0/255.255.128.0 gw 172.18.145.106| 
Interface out| Ethernet2/5.103| 
IP| 172.18.145.105/255.255.255.252| 
'''

print org_str

soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(raw_str)

tables = soup.findAll('table')
for cur_table in tables:
    print ""
    col_sizes = {}

    # Figure out the column sizes
    for tr in cur_table.findAll('tr'):
        tds = tr.findAll('td')
        cur_col_sizes = {col : max(len(td.text), col_sizes.get(col, 0)) for (col, td) in enumerate(tds)}
        col_sizes.update(cur_col_sizes)

    # Print the data, padded using the detected column sizes
    for tr in cur_table.findAll('tr'):
        tds = tr.findAll('td')
        line_strs = [("%%-%ds" % col_sizes[col]) % (td.text or "IP") for (col, td) in enumerate(tds)]
        line_str  = "| %s |" % " | ".join(line_strs)
        print line_str
```

Comment: Your code suffers of the same problem the guy's above code suffers. See the "edit 2". When I have that in my table, the output comes out all not aligned...

Comment: I'm going off what you put in your question. What's unaligned, the IPs?

Comment: Look at edid 3 please and test your code on it. It doesn't work :(

Comment: Well, if the first column is 1 raw of text but the second is 3 raws of text and so not equal, I want that in the first column to put a "placeholder" just to not break the rest...